# Julia : Make method take array as parameter

Tags: julia

I'm currently programming in Julia and I want a method (The constructor of class ProbData) to take an array of a defined type as its parameter. What I'm currently doing is:

```
function ProbData(variables::AbstractArray{BaseVariable, 1})
    instance = new()

    instance.numPara = size(variables, 1)
    instance.numRand = 0

    for x = variables
        if x.variableType != "Det"
            instance.numRand += 1
        end
    end

    instance.getNumPara = function()
        return instance.numPara
    end

    instance.getNumRand = function()
        return instance.numRand
    end

    return instance
end
```

BaseVariable is an abstract that has three subtypes. When I try to:

```
x = DetVariable("test", 0.15)
P = ProbData([x])
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: 'convert' has no method matching convert(::Type{ProbData}, ::Array{DetVariable.jl,1})
```

How can I fix this? I've just learned this language for a few days, so if you can point out what I shouldn't have done, I would appreciate it as well.

Edit: I've found out that if I defined the parameter array of the constructor to be an array of a certain type rather than an array of an abstract, the code would work properly. However, I need the parameter to be an array, whose elements could be of any subtype of BaseVariable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the function declaration to:

```
function ProbData{T<:BaseVariable}(variables::AbstractArray{T, 1})
```